# why does this conditional logic work?

Tags: verilog, if

I'm toying with outputs for an LCD on my FPGA. When I press the button, I want it to display the number 6. Instead, it is displaying 6 constantly, unless I press reset button, at which point the entire screen goes blank, which it should.

```
module LCD(CLOCK_50,LCD_DATA,LCD_RW,LCD_RS,LCD_EN,BUTTON);

input [2:0] BUTTON;

wire button;
wire button2;

assign button2 = ~BUTTON[2];

assign button = ~BUTTON[0];


input CLOCK_50;

output
LCD_RS,
LCD_RW,
LCD_EN;

output [7:0] LCD_DATA;
reg [7:0] D;
reg [1:0] Op, En;




////module clk_div_10(clk,reset,clk_out);

clk_div_10 clk(CLOCK_50,,clock);
wire clock;



 FPGA_2_LCD DUT1(clock,LCD_RS,LCD_RW,LCD_EN,LCD_DATA,
 ,D,Op,En,button2);

 always @(posedge clock or posedge button) 

 if (button == 1) begin

        D <= 8'b00110110;
        En <= 1'b1;
        Op <= 1'b1;
 end



endmodule
```

Comment: How your `button` is connected? If it is normally high this is what should happen...

Comment: sorry I dont understand? Its soldered to the board.

Comment: *How*? You don't just solder stuff. You solder it in a specific way, usually described by a schematic.

Comment: if you're getting at why do I have a NOT assignment for the button, it is because everything is backwards on the board. If the button isnt pressed there is a signal, so you have to negate everything.

Comment: This is hardly a valid description. Do you have a schematic?

Comment: https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-54986/l/altera-schematic-file-for-p0037-de0-development-board

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is the DE0 board, they are normally high, that's the problem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 always @(posedge clock or posedge button) 
 if (button == 1) begin

        D <= 8'b00110110;
        En <= 1'b1;
        Op <= 1'b1;
 end
```

Let me be your FPGA. Allow me to explain what hardware I have been told to have.

---

Ok, so we are powering on, lets power-on reset all of our registers.

Lets see now, ok, we have a clocked always block here, that means I have some flip-flops. Ooo, I also have an asynchronous reset called `button` which is active high, what does the always block tell me to do under this reset condition. Because I have been told what to do at reset, **I'll do this during power-on reset as well** - hmm, it says to set `D` to 54, great I'll do that.

Now I am have finished powering on and come out of reset, lets start running.

Ok, so a clock edge comes, what do I do with the register? Ok, reset (`button`) is not asserted. Hmm, it seems the person wants me to retain my value. Great sorted.

Now `button` is high. What do I do? Ok, I'll reset my register to 54 again. Woop, done.

Now the user pushed my global reset. Time to fully reconfigure. All outputs to HIGH-Z! Arrrrrg. I've gone blank. What do I do?

Yay, they've released my global reset button. Time to load my memory again.

...

And back to the beginning.

---

**TL;DR;**

You may notice a pattern here? Never does the value of `D` get set to anything other than 54.

A hint for next time, in all seriousness. FPGA tools like Quartus which you will be using for your DE0 board have RTL netlist viewers. Once you synthesize your design, you can load the netlist to see a graphical representation of what hardware has been inferred. This will quickly give you an idea of what is going on.

Comment: but how does it get set to 54 to begin with if I never press the button. Shouldn't the lines following the "if" only occur if i press the button?

Comment: Read my answer closely, I explain it.

Comment: @MattJD it gets set during power-on reset or when you push the global reset button. Quartus will have inferred that 54 is your start-up value from the asynchronous reset you described with your `if` statement. Remember, you are not writing a program, you are describing hardware. If you are not specific about what you want it to do, it will simplify things to the most efficient hardware that meets your vague specifications.

Comment: I was just going to reply its because I never set an initial value that represents a blank screen.

Comment: The RTL viewer comment jsut opened an entire world to me. It has a state machine viewer too!

Comment: I like the way you explain it Tom and everything you say is entirely valid, however I also think this problem is also a bit simpler than that. @MattJD you're using the DE0 board, these have active low buttons. Aka. 1 when not pressed and 0 when pressed, if you have a look it even says this in the manual [Read this paragraph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lZ5t.jpg) You need to change your if statement to (button == 0)

Comment: @Hayman while you are correct about the buttons being active low, it is irrelevant here. The code as it stands does not infer any hardware beyond a constant output value because D is always a constant value as specified by its inferred reset behaviour. If you run the program as it stands, it will immediately provide the same output even if you hold the input button pressed (i.e. 0) while and after the FPGA is reset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an else to your if statement.  Currently, when button becomes high, D is set. But D is never reset. So it will always contain the set value. When the FPGA starts button is pulled high by the pull-up resistors.

Also, I would change the always statement to only trigger on the clock rising edge. There is no need for the button to be a clock. The bouncing of the button can introduce meta stability.

Comment: Actually `D` is only ever "reset". For most if not all FPGAs an `always` block can only have a single edge sensitive signal (the clock) and optionally one edge sensitive reset declaration which is subsequently used in an `if` statement. Here `button` fulfils the criteria of being the reset signal.

Answer (score 0):

From looking through your comments you mention you're using the DE0 board from Altera.

What this problem boils down to is the fact that this board has normally high switches and you treating it like it's normally low.

[image: Extract from DE0 manual]

What you're program is saying is *"set the LCD display to this if the button is high".* The button is always high unless it's pressed hence why the number 6 appears.
The surefire way to test this is to hold the button down and then reset the device. My guess is that the number 6 won't appear until you let go of the button.

Changing your if statement from:

```
if (button == 1) begin
```

to

```
if (button == 0) begin
```

will solve your immediate issue, however what Tom and User110971 say is also important, your statement does need an *"Else"* in there.

Comment: This would work, if I didn't already negate the actual button. The pin assignment is BUTTON[1]. I then created a wire button and assigned ~BUTTON[1] to it. Tom Carpenter's explanation hit the nail on the head.